# How to make a POST request (Angular)?

Tags: angular

I need to send a POST request which accepts username and password like given below,

*{"username":"password"}*

Eg : {"admin":"admin123"}

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

      return this.http.post<any>(url,{username:password},httpOptions)
          .pipe(map(user => {
             //code
  }
```

How to send this in post request?

Comment: That is covered in https://angular.io/guide/http - please research before asking

Answer (score 1):

Using *HttpClient*, the post() function allows you to pass a body as a second parameter :

Inside your service :

```
constructor(private http: HtpClient) {}

public postData() {
 return this.http.post(url, {username: 'foo', password: 'bar'});
}
```

I would recommend you to take a look on the angular tutorial on [how to send data to the server](https://angular.io/guide/http#sending-data-to-a-server)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, and the username and password go in the `body` you're passing here. It's helpful to make it more generic like this, so you can use this with a variety of `post` requests:

```
sendPostRequest(req: string, body: object): any {
  return this.http.post(`${APIConfig.url}/${req}`, body).toPromise();
}
```

I also like to use `.toPromise()` because it allows you to you `async/await` in the component that calls this service.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private http: HtpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.http.post(url, {"username":"Nik", "password":"Test123"}).subscribe(response => {
    // handle response body
  },
  error => {
    // handle error response
  }); 
}
```